# Implement class without scope resolution operator?

Tags: c++

If I declare my class in a header file, is there any way to implement the class without all those annoying scope resolution operators? I don't like rewriting the class name for each member. I think I have tried to do it like this before:

In A.h

```
#if !defined(a_h)
#define a_h
class A {
    int function (int);
    int foo (void);
};
#endif
```

In A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
class A { 
     int function (int number) {
         return 2* number;
     }
    int foo (void){
        return 2;
    }
}
```

but got some error (unable to test it now unfortunately).

Comment: I know. I am wondering if there is a workaround to save typing...

Comment: You can implement it inline in the header

Comment: So there is no alternative ? Maybe a macro of some sort ?

Comment: I dont want to have it inline I read that it might get bad with several translation units or something..

Comment: would `#define define_A_member(return_type) return_type A::` and then `define_A_member(int) function(int number) {...` work for you?  (This wrapper is trivially altered to support templates, which is nice)

Comment: This is really too simple to try to do something off-the-wall. Just type up your header copy/paste the defs in the imp file, type `your_class::` once and copy/past it where it belongs. Or, learn another language.

Comment: Then I would need a special program to allow several copy paste slots so I can copy paste actual code tht i need.

Comment: Unfortunately that would force me to marshal c++ code to another language which i dont want to..

Comment: `Ctrl-C` `Ctrl-V` or assembly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pre-processor macros to make it easier.

```
#include "A.h"
#ifdef _
#undef _
#endif
#define _(fun) A::fun

int _(function)(int number)
{
   return 2* number;
}

int _(foo)(void)
{
   return 2;
}
```

**However ...**

You shouldn't necessarily do something just because you can.

Using a preprocessor macro to hide an important construct of the language is ill-advised. Here are some things to think about before you go down that path.

1. The time spent writing `<ClassName>::` fades in comparison to the amount time spent in writing rest of the code in any program that does something useful.
2. The amount of time you will spend in debugging and maintaining a program will be much much higher than the amount of time you'll spend in writing `<ClassName>::`.
3. When you have multiple classes in a `.cpp` file, you will have a hard time clearly seeing which function corresponds to which class if you adopt the same policy for all classes.
4. When you are debugging, you will be frustrated that you won't be able to see the fully qualified function name when you step into a function.
5. The loss of clarity is too expensive a price to pay in exchange for saving a few key strokes while implementing the member functions of a class.

I am speaking from experience. I work in a project where one of the class names is `INR_DynamicallyTypedLowFidelityLeafComponentRepresentation`. I wouldn't use a preprocessor macro to hide even that long a name.

Comment: Thanks, might try that.

Comment: Be careful though, if you include that header in many other files your compile time will explode!

Comment: It should be safe if i throw a undef _ at the end of the file? Why would compile time explode?

Comment: @Emil It's safe, but it's disgusting.

Comment: Well i think mysuperlongclassnameincamelcase::fun is more disgusting :D

Comment: For increased readability you could call it `A_colon_colon` instead of `_`

Comment: @M.M That defeats the macro purpose.